Can anyone interprete my dream please?
Asalum alaikm I had a dream someone like an old man ordered me to read Ayat al-Kursi Sharif. My environment during my dream was the room where I was sleeping. he told me don't hesitate in your hajat,I had a hajat that I prayed for alot and became disappoint,ramadan was near and I told myself that I'll make dua for my hajat as last time and after that I wont make dua,that night I was very disappointed when I woke up it was3:30 am first or second night of ramadan can anyone interprete this dream please?

I relay hate those uncommeted down-votes you have been given. But here is not the place for interpreting dreams, or even give personal advice.  In general terms, may are praying for personal or family things. What of it granted, Allah knows best. Don't quit your faith but seek better understanding.

Personally I think that dream is very positive although not sure
But would it be possible for you to ask a local sheikh or if that's difficult , an imam maybe?
Because personally I would do that if I dont know.
Jazakallah for reading and May Allah bless you and give you jannah al firdaus
